# Mail from server going to junk folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am working on an ASP.NET website. I have a page where I'm sending mail. Here the user adds the recipient; the sender is his own id. When I run this application on my location machine the mail properly comes in my inbox but as I paste that page on the server and try mailing the mail comes in Junk folder.

Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Sever IP is added in Relay list of SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with code and more about setting your SMTP servers up properly in the realm of DNS and/or discussing it with your hosting provider. According to your post, your ability to send mail is not the issue - its more about how the receiving agent treats your email (tags it according to some rule, etc.). The only difference being "who" sends the email (your local machine, vs your server).

There are [Postmaster resources - this one from everyone's favorite- AOL](http://postmaster.aol.com/) that you may find useful. You can also check with [DNS blacklists](http://www.spamhaus.org/) if your server's IP is (unfortunately) listed.